# Epipolar line from fundamental matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, geometry

My objective is to draw the epiplar line in right image corresponding a point in left image from fundamental matrix.

I read two images

```
imgG = imread('ImgLeft.BMP');
imgD = imread('ImgRight.BMP');

%normilized matrix
N=[2/320    0       -1;
   0        2/240   -1;
   0        0        1];
```

make a loop to read 9 points to create fundamental matrix

```
   for i=1:n
imshow(imgG); 
[xg(i),yg(i)] = ginput(1);
xg(i) = xg(i)/norm([xg(i),yg(i)]);
yg(i) = yg(i)/norm([xg(i),yg(i)]);
imshow(imgD);
[xd(i),yd(i)] = ginput(1);
xd(i) = xd(i)/norm([xd(i),yd(i)]);
yd(i) = yd(i)/norm([xd(i),yd(i)]);
end

 for j=1:n
A(j,1:9) = [xg(j)*xd(j),yg(j)*xd(j),xd(j),xg(j)*yd(j),yg(j)*yd(j),yd(j),xg(j),yg(j), 1];
end
```

to solve to equation A*F = 0 I juste use SVD

```
[U,D,V] = svd(A);
F= reshape(V(:,9),3,3);
[U1,D1,V1] = svd(F);
D1(3,3) = 0; 
F = U1*D1*transpose(V1);
F = N.' * F * N;
```

For the rest of code I tried to draw the epipolar line of a choosing point but the epipolar line didn't across the correspondant point in the other image (see the picture at below)
Look image : http://s11.postimg.org/mk51x9u5f/image.png

```
    imshow(imgG);
[px,py] = ginput(1);
a= F(1,1)*px+F(1,2)*py+F(1,3);
b= F(2,1)*px+F(2,2)*py+F(2,3);
c= F(3,1)*px+F(3,2)*py+F(3,3);


a= a/norm([a,b,c]);
b=b/norm([a,b,c]);
c=c/norm([a,b,c]);

y1 = (-a-c)/b
y2 = (-a*320-c)/b

figure;
imshow(imgD);
hold on;
line([1,320],[y1,y2],'Color','g','LineWidth',2)
hold off;
```

Comment: ...didn't work *how*? Please be more specific, perhaps post some error messages

Comment: Look at image the epipolar line is not in right place 
http://s11.postimg.org/mk51x9u5f/image.png

Comment: I'm not sure if the fundamental matrix calculation is right

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately,i want to draw epipolar line on right image.

If i know points on left image and rotation matrix between left camera and right camera, how can i get Essential matrix for drawing epipolar line on right image?
(so, i don't use 8-points algorithm)

I don't know points on right image and translate.

Also, if i don't know Intrinsic parameter, can i draw epipolar line?

Thank you to read my ask.

```
import numpy as np
human_joints = [[555.386  , 404.46036],
    [530.7022 , 406.29446],
    [525.9443 , 495.40973],
    [524.181  , 567.4924],
    [580.57495, 402.6036],
    [570.3312 , 490.75363],
    [565.38043, 574.8825],
    [552.14886, 357.5693],
    [558.4907 , 305.46155],
    [550.31824, 286.06784],
    [553.5209 , 265.68933],
    [581.8808 , 324.2853],
    [592.437  , 379.61853],
    [585.6859 , 423.94284],
    [532.6373 , 319.59055],
    [513.3627 , 373.28836],
    [497.28082, 419.97885]]

K_l = np.array([[1.14967570e+03, 0.00000000e+00, 5.08848622e+02],
   [0.00000000e+00, 1.14759162e+03, 5.08064917e+02],
   [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00]])

K_r = np.array([[1.14551134e+03, 0.00000000e+00, 5.14968197e+02],
       [0.00000000e+00, 1.14477393e+03, 5.01882019e+02],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00]])

R = np.array([[ 0.7133686 ,  0.10367816, -0.69307726],      # left to right 
            [-0.15670811,  0.98755177, -0.01356717],
            [ 0.68304305,  0.11828922,  0.72073563]])

print(right_img.shape) # (1002,1000,3)
print(left_img.shape) # (1002,1000,3)
```